Can't change the fill color of a SVG element with Javascript
I'm puzzled by SVG fills. I can't seem to set the fill of a rect with styling, and I can't set the fill of a rect with Javascript. With this test program, element cal23 is black. Element cal24 is transparent, showing the underlying yellow through, but the Javascript doesn't set the fill color to red.


document.getElementById('cal23').style.backgroundColor = "red";
document.getElementById('cal24').style.backgroundColor = "red";
console.log('Ran setColor on cal23 and cal24');
body {
  background-color: yellow;
}
<svg xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 20.2 11">
  <style>
    #cal23 { fill="none'; }
  </style>

  <rect id="cal23" width="10" height="10" x="0" y="0" stroke-width="0.2" stroke="orange"/>
  <text x="5" y="5" font-size="1.5" text-anchor="middle" fill="black">Test</text>

  <rect id="cal24" width="10" height="10" x="10" y="0" stroke-width="0.2" stroke="pink" fill="none"/>
  <text x="15" y="5" font-size="1.5" text-anchor="middle">Test</text>
</svg>




I just realized I was trying to set background color and not the fill. I changed it to .setAttribute('fill', 'red') and it worked. But why can't I style a rect's fill?

Your style is formatted incorrectly, using an equal sign instead of a colon and opening with a double-quote and ending with a single quote. The quotes need to match. Try: #cal23  {fill: 'none';}

and CSS is fill : none not fill = none

This question is similar to: Changing SVG image color with javascript. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

you can try this property .style.fill. For SVG tag, backcolor style can not work
 <script>
     document.getElementById('cal23').style.fill="red";
     document.getElementById('cal24').style.fill="red";
 <script>


Please replace your javascript with this. If the DOM is accessed in a javascript, placing the code within the load event handler ensures the code only runs after the DOM is loaded. Please refer to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/load_event.
I have used the document.querySelector instead of document.getElementById. The document.querySelector provides more consistency and flexibility.
The document.querySelector supports CSS based selectors and single ID-based selections.
<script>
        addEventListener("load", (event) => {;
        document.querySelector('#cal23').style.fill = "red";
        document.querySelector('#cal24').style.fill = "red";
        console.log('Ran setColor on cal23 and cal24');
        })
</script>


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
